# PHP check if number decimal is larger than .3

Tags: php, numbers, int, numeric

I'm using the following to determine if a value has a decimal. For example `$val = 3.3;`

```
if (is_numeric( $val ) && floor( $val ) != $val) {
    return true;
}
```

How can I check of the value's decimal is equal to .3 or greater?

Comment: Can the 5 users with 1000+ rep perhaps try searching for a duplicate instead of answering?

Comment: Programming is breaking up a larger problem into smaller steps which you can solve separately. Once you have the decimal part of a number, comparing that decimal part to the desired number is trivial. It's almost as easy as putting two and two together. Read [ask] and show your research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subtract `floor($val)` from `$val` to get the decimal value of `$val`. Eg:

```
if( $val - floor($val) >= 0.3  ) {
     return true;
}
```

Note that it won't work if `$val` is negative, you can use `abs` for it to work:

```
if( abs($val) - floor(abs($val)) >= 0.3 ) {}
```

Or something like:

```
// if the negative number should be greater than 0.3
if( $val - floor($val) >= 0.3 && abs($val) - floor(abs($val)) >= 0.3  ) {}
// if the negative number should be less than 0.3
if( $val - floor($val) >= 0.3 && abs($val) - floor(abs($val)) <= 0.3 ) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ty this:

```
function fractionalPartOfDoubleVal($doub){
    // $doub = +1.4;
    // $whole = floor($doub);
    if ($doub > 0){     
        $whole = floor($doub);     
    } else {
        $whole = ceil($doub);     
    }

    $fractionalPart = $doub - $whole;
    if  ($fractionalPart > 0.3){
     // further processing
    }

    return abs($fractionalPart);
}

$posFractionalPart = fractionalPartOfDoubleVal(2.7);
echo ($posFractionalPart);
$negFractionalPart = fractionalPartOfDoubleVal(-2.7);
echo ($negFractionalPart);
```

Comment: careful OP: equal to .3 or greater implies >=

Comment: Have added link to stackoverflow answer which allows for negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can get the integer part of your float, and subtract it from the original:

```
$value = 3.3;
$integer = floor($value); // 3
$decimal = $value - $integer; //0.3
if($decimal >= 0.3){ //true
    //your stuff
}
```